# Find bases for N(T) and R(T) and verify the Dimension Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

We have
$$
T\pmatrix{a11&a12&a13\\a21&a22&a23\\a31&a32&a33}= \pmatrix{a11+a12+a13&a21+a22+a23\\a21+a22+a23&0}.
$$

I know what the Dimension Theorem is and by looking at the equation I can tell that $a11+a12=-a13$ and so on shows that the null space contains more than just the zero vector, however I struggle in figuring out how to express the bases of $N(T)$ and $R(T)$.

Comment: It should not be hard to find some elements of the range, and then to prove that those elements are linearly independent and span the range. Try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try some small numbers, easiest to play with $1$ and $0$.

For $N(T)$, as you started you get these $3$ equations ($2$ of them are the same) as $-a_{11}-a_{12} =a_{13}$, so that $a_{11}$, $a_{12}$ and $a_{21}$, $a_{22}$ can be *anything*, only $a_{13}$ and $a_{23}$ are bound to them. Also, $a_{31},\ a_{32},\ a_{33}$ can be anything.

So, consider these elements of $N(T)$:

- $a_{11}=1$, rest is $0$ ($\implies a_{13}=-1$)
- $a_{12}=1$, rest is $0$ ($\implies a_{13}=-1$)
- $a_{21}=1$, rest is $0$ ($\implies a_{23}=-1$)
- and so on...

Answer (score 0):

quite sure:

basis for $N(T) = $$\pmatrix{1&0&-1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$
$\pmatrix{0&1&-1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$$\pmatrix{0&0&0\\1&0&-1\\0&0&0}$$\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0}$$\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&0&0}$$\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0}$$\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1}$

basis for $R(T) = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$

edit: I think this is what Berci said

Comment: Yes, almost. I just haven't found my '*matrix*' switch on the keyboard :)
The last two ones of $N(T)$ are not correct, $a_{31},\ a_{32},\ a_{33}$ are free.

Comment: ah, you're right!

Comment: Did you notice that every matrix in the range is symmetric?

Comment: I corrected according to the comments.